# PHP Mysql: Avoid overflow on pageviews?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So I have certain profile pages that needs to have page views. I stored the view data in mysql and php (actually laravel). Basic idea is to add view by 1 every time the profile is visited.

Basic idea is to add a php code in the profile page, like

```
$page->view += 1; $page->save();
```

But what if the user hits f5 several times? It will cause the query to run a lot and I fear it will eventually slow the app.

I was thinking of making a prompt with js when user hits f5 and an ajax call to add the view. But I was wondering if there is a better solution (like, how did youtube do their views)?

Comment: Please note that inline code spans (`like this`) [shouldn't be used for highlighting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990), only for code in sentences. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can count the views after a certain amount of time on the page.

To achieve this, you will need a delayed javascript function like:

`setTimeout(function(){countView()},3000);` (3 second delay)

Where `countView()` should be an ajax call to a function that runs `$page->view += 1; $page->save();`

And since Ajax calls are asynchronous, the execution will not delay your application flow, although a simple increment on a page-view table should not do much harm in terms of performance

Comment: The question states PHP. Also, this would not work because they could still refresh many times, except they would need to wait 3 seconds. And more time would lock the page.

Comment: What part of `asynchronous` are you missing? It will not lock the page.

Comment: LOL, wait wait? are you mad? Dont take this personally, we are just discussing programming man. :) My main point was that they could still increase the pagecount shortly after.

Answer (score 0):

This will work as long as the user doesnt delete the cookies.

```
if ($_COOKIE['returning']!="yes")
 {
   // first visit!
 }
setcookie("returning", "yes", time()+360000);
```

Another way would be to log the IP in a database and check if user already visited, but the code is more complex than i can post right now. I will edit the post later if accepted.

Comment: You do realize that OP has not stated anything about logged users (different username) and your code will prevent views on multiple users from being incremented.  `$_COOKIE['username']` will be set when the first profile is visited but will it will also prevent increments on other profiles.

Comment: Yes. I do realize. "username" keyword can be anything.